# Swapping an unlimited number of columns

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, columns

I have a file with columns. See below for an example:

```
a b c ... z  
1 2 3 ... 26
```

I'd like to swap all columns where the 1st becomes the last, the second becomes the one before last...etc..

```
z y x ... a  
26 25 24 ... 1
```

Is there a one liner (`awk` or `sed`) that does this?
I know one can use `awk` when there is only a couple columns,
but I'd like to be able to do this on files with thousands of columns.

`tac` does this perfectly for lines.
I guess I am looking for the equivalent for columns.

`rev` hasn't worked for me, as it also swaps content in the column.

Comment: `perl -lane 'print join " ", reverse @F'`

Answer (score 15):

```
awk '{for(i=NF;i>0;i--)printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
```

Comment: I did too hard work for such a simple task. Always simpler it's better. **+1**

Answer (score 10):

You could do it with a small python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Swaps order of columns in file, writes result to a file.
# usage: program.py input_file output_file

import sys, os

out = []

for line in open(sys.argv[1], 'r'):
    fields = line.split()
    rev = ' '.join(list(reversed(fields)))
    out.append(rev)

f = open(sys.argv[2], 'w')
f.write(os.linesep.join(out))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind python then this one-liner will reverse the order of space separated columns in every line:

```
paddy$ cat infile.txt 
a b c d e f g h i j k l
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
a e i o u
paddy$ python3 -c 'with open("infile.txt") as f: print("\n".join(" ".join(line.rstrip().split()[::-1]) for line in f))'
l k j i h g f e d c b a
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
u o i e a
paddy$
```

The above works with python2.7 too:

```
paddy$ python2.7 -c 'with open("infile.txt") as f: print("\n".join(" ".join(line.rstrip().split()[::-1]) for line in f))'
l k j i h g f e d c b a
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
u o i e a
paddy$
```

Comment: This method is the fastest of all the ansers I've tested.

Answer (score 4):

One way using `awk`.

Content of `infile`:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
a e i o u
```

Run following `awk` command:

```
awk '{
    ## Variable 'i' will be incremented from first field, variable 'j'
    ## will be decremented from last field. And their values will be exchanged.
    ## The loop will end when both values cross themselves.
    j = NF; 
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
        if ( j - i < 1 ) { 
            break;
        } 
        temp = $j; 
        $j = $i; 
        $i = temp; 
        j--; 
    }
    print;
}' infile
```

With following result:

```
l k j i h g f e d c b a
12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
u o i e a
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use `tac` you just need to transpose the input before and after. This can be done with the spreadsheet calculator `sc` and its sidekick `psc`:

```
< infile psc -S -r | sc -W% - | tac | psc -S -r | sc -W% - > outfile
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1730513/1331399).

This works best when all the columns are filled.

**infile**

```
 a b c d e f g h i  j  k  l
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 A B C D E F G H I  J  K  L
```

**outfile**

```
  l  k  j i h g f e d c b a
 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  L  K  J I H G F E D C B A
```

#### Edit

As noted by *PeterO* `sc` has a hard limit of 702 columns, so that is the maximum size supported by this method.

Comment: It converts numbers to floating points (for me) eg. `1` -> `1.00`. Also, I get errors for lines more than 702 fields wide. It seem to be relate to a numeric limit of *32768*... but it is quite fast, asis.

Comment: I do not see the floating point conversion, but adding `-S` to the `psc` command should interpret everything as strings. With regards to the 702 column limit, that's a hard limit because only A to ZZ columns are supported (26 + 26 * 26), I'll add a comment about that.

Comment: Actually, the floating point issue is ok.I looked further into it, and I discovered that I shouldn't check results as I'm hurrying out the door..  The floating points only occur *after* it hits the *702* limit... It is faster than the python answers for **1** line of 702 fields, but for 100 lines it becomes the slowest of all the given methods :( .. It must have a shorter start-up time than python.

Answer (score 3):

This is slow, but it does have one redeeming feature. It maintains the width of field separators, when they are wider than a single character. FWIW: If you run this script twice, the result is identical to the original.

Here is the script.

```
awk '{ eix = length($0) 
       for( fn=NF; fn>0; fn--) { dix=eix
            while( substr($0,dix,1) ~ /[ \t]/ ) dix--
            printf "%s%s", substr($0,dix+1,eix-dix), $fn
            dix-=length($fn); eix=dix }
       print substr($0,1,dix)
    }' "$file"
```

Here are some time comparisons. The test file contained 1 line.

```
                      fields           fields     
                      10,0000          10,000,000

user11136 {python} | real  0.029s     real  3.235s
reversible? no     | user  0.032s     user  2.008s
                   | sys   0.000s     sys   1.228s

jmp {python}       | real  0.078s     real  5.045s
reversible? no     | user  0.068s     user  4.268s
                   | sys   0.012s     sys   0.560s

rush {awk}         | real  0.120s     real  10.889s
reversible? no     | user  0.116s     user   8.641s
                   | sys   0.008s     sys    2.252s

petero {awk}       | real  0.319s     real  35.750s
reversible? yes    | user  0.304s     user  33.090s
                   | sys   0.016s     sys    2.660s
```

Answer (score 3):

This pipeline is faster than the fastest other answer by a significant factor (see results). It uses `tr` and `tac`. It does need to utilize 2 ASCII bytes (\x00-\x7F) which don't exist in your data.

`\x00` is typically a good choice, as is `\x01`, but you can use any ASCII byte which is not in the data.

In this example, SPACE and TAB as the delimiters characters. Delimiters can be multi-byte or single. The output delimiter is a single space.

Here is the command. The filename shows the `numberof fields` _x `number of lines`

```
 <"$file" tr ' \t\n' '\0\0\1' |tr -s '\0' '\n' |tac |tr '\n' ' ' |tr '\1' '\n'
```

---

If you want/need to check for the unused bytes, you can check beforehand with this optional `awk` script.  The overall time, even when running this optional script, is still significantly faster than other metods (so far :).. Here is the pre-processing script.

```
o=($(<"$file" char-ascii-not-in-stream)); x="${o[0]}"; y="${o[1]}"
<"$file" tr ' \t\n' "$x$x$y" |tr -s "$x" '\n' |tac |tr '\n' ' ' | tr '$y' '\n' >"$file".$user
```

This is the awk script: `char-ascii-not-in-stream`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{c[$0]} END{for(i=0;i<=127;i++) {if(sprintf("%c", i) in c);else {printf "\\%03o ",i}}}
```

---

The second set of times, for this script, include `char-ascii-not-in-stream`'s time.

```
Peter.O {tr,tac,tr} ==== file_10_x10000
real    0m0.013s    0m0.015s
user    0m0.020s    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.008s    0m0.012s   

user11136 {python} ===== file_10_x10000
real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.048s
sys     0m0.008s

jmp {python} =========== file_10_x10000
real    0m0.160s
user    0m0.160s
sys     0m0.000s

rush {awk} ============= file_10_x10000
real    0m0.121s
user    0m0.120s
sys     0m0.000s

##############################################

Peter.O {tr,tac,tr} ==== file_1000_x1000
real    0m0.048s    0m0.059s
user    0m0.040s    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.040s    0m0.048s

user11136 {python} ===== file_1000_x1000
real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.136s
sys     0m0.028s

jmp {python} =========== file_1000_x1000
real    0m0.327s
user    0m0.320s
sys     0m0.008s

rush {awk} ============= file_1000_x1000
real    0m0.832s
user    0m0.820s
sys     0m0s012s

##############################################

Peter.O {tr,tac,tr} ==== file_1000000_x50
real    0m5.221s    0m6.458s
user    0m4.208s    0m5.248s
sys     0m2.624s    0m2.396s

user11136 {python} ===== file_1000000_x50
real    0m16.286s
user    0m10.041s
sys     0m5.148s

jmp {python} =========== file_1000000_x50
real    0m22.845s
user    0m20.705s
sys     0m1.140s

rush {awk} ============= file_1000000_x50
real    0m44.793s
user    0m43.583s
sys     0m0.848s

##############################################
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without *print**f***:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""} {for(k=NF;k>0;--k) {print $k; if (k==1) print "\n"; else print " "}} ' file
```